# Fswatch with different extensions

Tags: regex, bash, fswatch

I need to watch files with different extensions, and run an .sh command after every change. With fswatch, I've been able to watch each extension separately, like:

```
fswatch *.html | (while read; do ./dev.sh; done) 

fswatch index-static/*.js | (while read; do ./dev.sh; done) 

fswatch index-static/*.scss | (while read; do ./dev.sh; done)
```

If I run these commands in different terminal windows, I get what I want... triger the .sh command, after a file with (html|scss|js) extensions has changed.

However, I'm not been able to consolidate this into a single command.

This is running on MaxOS El Capitan, if you need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no direct experience with `fswatch`, but according to the [usage](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch#usage) you can provide multiple paths at once, e.g.:

```
fswatch *.html index-static/*.js index-static/*.scss | (while read; do ./dev.sh; done)
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: It does indeed! I would've sworn that I'd tried this before... but apparently it wasn't the case. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Glad I could help :)